# implementing a linked list with StockList

Tags: java, interface, linked-list, iterator

EDIT: Thanks for the help. My tutor gave me an assignment to do with this code and iv'e put in all of the given code snippets into my code and tried to correct my code. However one thing im stuck on is that the Linked list class has "class, enum, Interface expected". I tried using both the Stock Item and Stock List class in the parameters of Stock Linked List but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package computercompany;

/**
 *
 * @author obliv_000
 */
public class StockItem
{
    private String itemID;
    private String itemDesc;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private int reOrderLevel;
    public String getItemID()
    {
        return itemID;
    }
    public String getItemDesc()
    {
        return itemDesc;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }
    public int getReOrderLevel()
    {
        return reOrderLevel;
    }
    public StockItem(String itemsID, String itemsDesc, double p, int quant, 
            int rol)
    {
        itemID = itemsID;
        itemDesc = itemsDesc;
        quantity = quant;
        reOrderLevel = rol;
        price = p;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public void setReOrderLevel(int reOrderLevel)
    {
        this.reOrderLevel = reOrderLevel;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "itemID = " + getItemID() + ", itemDesc = " + getItemDesc() +
                ", price = " + getPrice() + ", quantify = " + getQuantity() +
                ", reOrderLevel = " + getReOrderLevel();
    }
    public String format()
    {
        return "The values for the following variables are:\nItemID: " + 
                getItemID() + "\nItemDesc: " + getItemDesc() + "\nPrice: " +
                getPrice() + "\nQuantify: " + getQuantity() + "\nReOrderLevel: "
                + getReOrderLevel();
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package computercompany;
/**
 *
 * @author obliv_000
 */
public interface StockList
{
    public StockLinkedList stock = new StockLinkedList();
    public void addItem(StockItem item);
    public void deleteItem(String itemID);
    public void updateItemPrice(String itemID, double price);
    public void updateItemQuantity(String itemID, int quantity);
    public void updateReOrderLevel(String itemID, int reOrderLevel);
    public String formatStockList(String list)
    {
        list = String.format
        ("ItemID    Description         Price    Qnty    Re-Order Level\n"
                + "******   ***********         *****   ****    **************\n");
        return list;
    }
    public String formatReOrderList()
    {
        ListIterator<StockItem> iterf = ItemList.listIterator();
        String reReOrderList = FormattedTitle;
        while(iterf.hasNext())
        {
            StockItem temp = iterf.next;
            int quant = temp.getQuantity();
            int reorder = temp.getReOrderLevel();
            if(quant<reorder)
            {
                formattedReOrder += iterf.next().format() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    ListIterator listIterator() 
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package computercompany;

/**
 *
 * @author obliv_000
 */
public class  StockLinkedList<StockList>
{
   private StockLinkedList<StockList> prevItem;
   private StockItem myItem; 
   private StockLinkedList<StockList> nextItem;
   public StockLinkedList(StockList item)
   {
       this(null, item, null);
   }
   public StockLinkedList(StockList item, StockLinkedList<StockList> previous,
           StockLinkedList next)
   {
       myItem = item;
       nextItem = next;
       prevItem = previous;
   }
    }
   public StockList getMyItem()
   {
       return myItem;
   }
   public StockLinkedList<StockList> getNextItem()
   {
       return nextItem;
   }
   public StockLinkedList<StockList> getPrevItem()
   {
       return prevItem;
   }
   public void setItem(StockList item)
   {
       myItem = item;
   }
   public void setPrevItem(StockLinkedList<StockList> previous)
   {
       prevItem = previous;
   }
   public void setNextItem(StockLinkedList<StockList> next)
   {
       nextItem = next;
   }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package computercompany;

import static computercompany.StockList.stock;

/**
 *
 * @author obliv_000
 */
public class StockListCLI
{
    private StockList stock = null;
    public StockListCLI(StockList stock)
    {
    }
    // Displays main menu and gets valid option from user
    public void doMenu() 
    {
    }
    // Obtain input for stock list operation
    // and invoke operation
    private void doAddItem() 
    {
        stockList.add(item);
    }
    private void doDeleteItem() 
    {
        Iterator<StockItem> itr = stockList.listIterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) 
        {
            StockItem item = itr.next();
            if(item.getItemID().equals(itemID)) 
            {
                itr.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void doUpdateItemPrice() 
    {
        ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
            if(item.getItemID().equals(itemID))
            {
                item.setPrice(price);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void doUpdateItemQuantity() 
    {
        ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
            if(item.getItemID().equals(itemID))
            {
                item.setReOrderLevel(reOrderLevel);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void doUpdateReOrderLevel() 
    {
        StockLinkedList itr = stock.listIterator();
        while(itr.setNextItem())
        {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
            if(item.getItemID().equals(itemID))
            {
                item.setQuantity(quantity);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Display contents of stock list
    private void doPrintStockList() 
    {
    }
    // Display contents of re-order list
    private void doPrintReorderLIst() 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use stack snippets for Java. They are for JavaScript and the two are far from the same thing.

Comment: How do i do snippets for java then?

Comment: Why would you put them back after they have been removed?

Comment: didn't even know they were removed and was gonna change it when i know how to do it for java

Comment: LOL did you put all my snippets together?? XD

Comment: I see no reason for them being separate. Not least because there is far too much code here for anyone to read anyway.

Comment: ah i know how to do it now and fair nuff

Answer (score 0):

Few notes/corrections:
1) don't implement any methods in your interface, use it as contract/ definition of services/method that will have to be provided by classes which implement it
2) think about the requirements for **your** class/interface - why do you need `LinkedList` at all? Is the order important?
3) implement all methods in your class

Answer (score 0):

So much wrong in one small code bit it's hard to know where to start.

An interface is something that should only put forward the signatures (return value, method name and parameters) of public methods.

An abstract class is a class that doesn't have a full implementation and can not be allocated it can only be inherited/subclassed.

Not knowing the purpose of this code it's hard to say much more. But assuming you do want an interface to say what can be done to a StockList and several types of implementation of a StockList (one of them being a StockLinkedList) you should have:

**interface class StockList** - defines possible operation on a stock list

**class StockItem** - item stored in a stock list

**class StockLinkedList** - implements StockList interface in a linked list fashion

**class StockLinkedListNode** - implements each element of the linked list with pointer to data and pointer to next (and previous if a double linked list) StockLinkedListNode

Good Luck!